# How would I make this button so that it only registers one click

Tags: python, pygame

I've made this button class that performs different actions depending on which button is clicked. At the moment when the buttons are clicked the actions are run multiple times. Is there anyway of making it so that the action only runs once.

```
def action_button(x,y,w,h,ic,ac,text, text_colour,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial black",20)
    text = font.render(text,True,(text_colour))
    screen.blit(text,[x+w/2-(text.get_rect().w/2),y+h/2-(text.get_rect().h/2)])
```

Comment: it is not class but function. Here is [example-class.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-click-cycle-color) with class Button.

Comment: problem is `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` which gives `True` all the time when you keep mouse's button pressed. Button treads it as many clicks and it executes function many times. Using `event` you can catch moment when button change state from unpressed to pressed and this will be only one moment so it will execute function only once. But using `event` need a lot of changes.

Comment: I see this button in many questions. It is probably from some tutorial .

Comment: I found this function in [Sentdex's tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-button-function-events/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` which gives `True` all the time when you keep mouse's button pressed. Button treads it as many clicks and it executes function many times. Using `event` you can catch moment when button change state from not-pressed to pressed and this will be only one moment so it will execute function only once.

But using event need a lot of changes. If you move all function to `for event` loop then it will run action only once but it will also draw button only once - when you click region where should be button.

Easy method is to split this function into two functions

- `action_button_draw` which only draw button and use it in old place
- `action_button_click` which only run action and put it in `for event` loop

  ```
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
          if event.button == 1: # 1 = left button, 3 = right button
              action_button_click(x, y, w, h, action)
  ```

  or at least

  ```
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
          action_button_click(x, y, w, h, action)
  ```

Function:

```
def action_button_click(x, y, w, h, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()

def action_button_draw(x, y, w, h, ic, ac, text, text_colour):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial black",20)
    text = font.render(text,True,(text_colour))
    screen.blit(text,[x+w/2-(text.get_rect().w/2),y+h/2-(text.get_rect().h/2)])
```

Minimal working example:

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480

FPS = 5

# --- functions ---

def action_button_click(x, y, w, h, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()

def action_button_draw(x, y, w, h, ic, ac, text, text_colour):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial black",20)
    text = font.render(text,True,(text_colour))
    screen.blit(text,[x+w/2-(text.get_rect().w/2),y+h/2-(text.get_rect().h/2)])

def test_action():
    print("clicked")

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        # MOUSEBUTTONDOWN is created only once,
        # when button changes state from "not-pressed" to "pressed"
        # so it is better for this job than "pygame.mouse.get_pressed()"
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                action_button_click(100, 100, 100, 50, test_action)

    # --- draws ----

    screen.fill([0,0,0]) # clear screen

    action_button_draw(100, 100, 100, 50, [255,0,0], [0,255,0], "Hello", [0,0,0])

    pygame.display.flip()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

These two functions you can also put in class and use class like in [example-class.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-click-cycle-color)

Original function works good only if executed action removes button from this region (ie. it removes menu and start game) but it has problem when button stays in the same place after clicking or you put new button in the same place (ie. when you go from menu to options which has button in the same place)

Answer (score 0):

## I solved it this way

I used this to make a button in pygame

```
def __init__(self):
    self.pressed = 0

def myfunc(self):
    if self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):    
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and self.pressed == 0:
            print("I clicked once")
            self.pressed = 1 # you cannot click anymore
        elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0,0,0):
            self.pressed = 0 # when you release the mouse button, you can again
```

## Now you click and it will show the text only once per click